# Conjunctive Simplification rule confusion

Tags: logic

I am doing a question where I have to show an argument is logically correct by building a proof of the conclusion from the premises, using logical equivalences and rules of inferences. I got everything but the last part correct as I do not understand how:

$$¬(t ∧ w) ∧ ¬(t ∧ r) ∧ ¬(w ∧ r)$$

is equal to:

$$¬(t ∧ r)$$

Using the conjunctive simplification rule which is this rule:
$$p ∧ q$$
$$------$$
$$p$$

Because surely using that rule it would simplify to ¬t ∧ ¬w, how does it equal ¬(t ∧ r)? What are the steps

Comment: These formulas aren't equivalent. E.g., take $t$ and $w$ to be true and $r$ to be false.

Comment: so their answer is wrong? im confused @RobArthan

Comment: If the question is asking you to prove that $\lnot(t \land w) \land  \lnot(t \land r) ∧ \lnot(w \land r)$ is logically equivallent to $\lnot(t \land r)$, then it is wrong.

Comment: Right, the statements aren’t logically equivalent, but the first one implies the other, which I think is all that is being asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\gamma$ be a set of well-formed formulas (WFFs), and $A$ and $B$ be metavariables that represent any WFF, and let $\implies$ represent logical consequence. Then the rule for conjunction elimination is as follows:

1. $\gamma \implies (A \land B)$
2. $\gamma \implies A$ (conjunction elimination, 1)
3. $\gamma \implies B$ (conjunction elimination, 1)

In English, if we can derive a conjunction from a set of premises, we can derive either conjunct from the same set of premises. What this is is a schema that we can put our WFFs into. Let's put what you have into this (I've added brackets to make it a WFF):

1. $(\lnot (t \land w) \land \lnot(t \land r))\land \lnot (w \land r) \implies (\lnot (t \land w) \land \lnot(t \land r))\land \lnot (w \land r)$ (this step is just declaring our assumption)
2. $(\lnot (t \land w) \land \lnot(t \land r))\land \lnot (w \land r) \implies (\lnot (t \land w) \land \lnot(t \land r))$ ($\land$E, 1)
3. $(\lnot (t \land w) \land \lnot(t \land r))\land \lnot (w \land r) \implies \lnot (t \land r)$ ($\land$E, 2)

So what's happening here? We're putting the WFF we want to derive something from into the schema and applying the rule - in this case twice. In the first instance, we're applying the rule to (1), where $A=(\lnot (t \land w) \land \lnot(t \land r))$ and $B=\lnot (w \land r)$, and deriving $A$. In the second instance we're applying it to (2), where $A=\lnot (t \land w)$ and $B=\lnot(t \land r)$, and we're deriving $B$. The set $\gamma$ in both instances doesn't change as we're not using any other premises.

It's probably a good idea to have an intuition about why we can use this rule. If, on some line of our proof, we derive a conjunction, what we've derived is something we're saying is true. Well, what does it mean for a conjunction to be true? To be true, both of its conjuncts need to be true. If both of the conjuncts are true then it follows that we can claim the first conjunct is true, and it follows we can say the second conjunct is true.

Comment: Fantastic explanation thanks a alot. I have a question though, if like RobPratt said I rearrange the original equation as A n B n C is equivalent to A n C n B, I can reach it in 1 step instead of 2 steps like you did if I 'Take p=¬(t∧r) and q=¬(t∧w)∧¬(w∧r)' right?

Comment: Honestly, depending on how strict you're being, you can just go ahead and extend the rule to 3 conjuncts and use $\land$E to select any of them - $A \land B \land C \implies B$, though technically incorrect in a number of ways, is fine. In answer to your specific question - conjunction is associative and commutative, and you can take that as a derived rule, so you can rearrange how you like one step at a time $(A \land B) \land C \implies C \land (A \land B) \implies (C \land A) \land B \implies B$. As you can see, even using these properties it would take more steps

Answer (score 2):

Addressing the various comments and main post:

1. Different conclusions (that are inequivalent to one another) can validly arise from the same set of premises, right? Naturally, the required proof differs depending on the required conclusion.
2. An inference rule is *consequential/implicational* $(\implies)$ in nature. Every equivalence $(\iff)$ (e.g. tautological equivalence) contains an implication $(\implies).$ So, it is valid to derive a conclusion using either or both. Naturally, the conclusion is typically not equivalent to the premises.
3. your suggested argument:

   [image]

   the book's given argument:

   [image]
4. \begin{align}&\text{not tall or not green} \\\iff &\text{not (tall and green)} \\\kern.8em\not\kern-.8em\iff &\text{not tall and not green} \\\iff &\text{not (tall or green)} \\\iff &\text{neither tall nor green}\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Take $p=\lnot(t \land r)$ and $q=\lnot(t \land w)\land\lnot(w \land r)$.

Comment: hmm okay so you can rearrange it. Also, does p∧q also imply q as well as p in the rule?

Comment: Yes, because $p \land q = q \land p$.

Comment: More formally, you can use the two rules for conjunction elimination to get from $p \land q \land r$ to $q$ in two steps. However, this doesn't really answer the question as conjunction elimination isn't reversible, so it doesn't deliver the equivalence the OP is looking for - unsurprisingly, since the formulas in the question aren't equivalent.

Comment: what I did was also correct but it didn't give me what I needed to reach the conclusion @RobArthan